# Highlight region of map and return counties within highlighted region

Tags: python, dictionary, choropleth

I am unsure whether there are any **tools** or python **libraries** available where I can **highlight or circle** a region on a map and it **return the counties** within the circle or region as text.

Any solutions?

Comment: This question is Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more

Answer (score 0):

You could check if each county gets in collision with the circle drawn, using its radius and center. If the county is in collision, then it is (at least partially) inside the circle.